# jQuery scoping issues between parent and iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scope

I use jQuery to create an iframe element which `onLoad` calls one of the parent's jQuery functions.
This causes `$ is not defined` for the parent when it calls additional jQuery functions.

It seems as if the iframe has caused a descoping if the parent's jQuery.

The iframe is not a page (`src="about:blank"`).

I think the iframe needs its own JavaScript/jQuery Environment but am having difficulty including it.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: `src="about:blank"`? What is the point? JavaScript interaction with iframes across domains is rather limited due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: please post your code. it will be easier for us.

Comment: @Matt This is Ajax Form Uploader code, hence the IFrame. The code is using [webtoolkit.aim.js](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this inside the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = window.parent.$;
</script>
```

This will allow the child window (assuming it is under the same domain) to use the parent's `$` variable (or whatever jQuery is set to)

Comment: Still struggling on this. I can call a JS function in the onLoad before the AIM.loaded is called. How do I incorporate the above solution into the Iframe from an additional JS function?